# How to set Hint font to italic with TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

How to set Hint font to **`italic`** with **`TextInputLayout`** in android.
With normal edit `strong text` text

" *Name* "

this will work if we set as **hint**, but not with `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would be in the form of a layout (and a string resource, if relevant) that you say will show the hint in italic, and a layout with `TextInputLayout` that will not.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom style for your TextInputLayout:

```
<style name="MyCustomAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <!-- your custom attributes -->
</style>
```

Then set the style

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomAppearance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can set the typeface to hint of any edit text:

in layout.xml :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and in java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Typeface font_yekan= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/italic.ttf");
        textInputLayout= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input1);
    textInputLayout.setTypeface(font_yekan);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

anyone looking in the future.

```
TextInputLayout inputlayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textField);
TypeFace font_robot_italic = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, your_desired_font);
inputlayout.setTypeFace(font_roboto_italic);
```

FYI, add a font file in the font resource directory before accessing it.